# CSS list with multiple counters doesn't count properly

Tags: list, css-counter

I have a `<ul>`-list with two different counters:

```
ul.numbered {
    counter-reset: alphaCounter, numberCounter;
}

ul.numbered li.numbered,
ul.numbered li.lettered {
    padding-left: 1.8em;
}

ul.numbered li.numbered:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    counter-increment: numberCounter;
    content: counter(numberCounter, decimal) ". "; 
}

ul.numbered li.lettered:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    counter-increment: alphaCounter;
    content: counter(alphaCounter, upper-alpha) ". "; 
}
```

This list counts the `li.lettered`-items properly with A., B., etc.. But the `li.numbered`-items always start with "1.". If I switch the order of the counter-reset to `counter-reset: numberCounter, alphaCounter;`, the numbers count properly and the letters always start with "A.".

From what I read, I set up the list properly, but well, appearantly not. Any help on this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, the problem was the comma between the two counters on `counter-reset`. The proper solution for resetting multiple counters in this case would be:

```
counter-reset: numberCounter alphaCounter;
```

[W3C, 12.4 Automatic counters and numbering](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#counters)

Comment: I ran into the same issue when attempting to reset multiple counters using the (also incorrect) syntax of `body {counter-reset: counter1; counter-reset: counter2;}` or `body {counter-reset: counter1;} body {counter-reset: counter2;}`. Apparently, listing the counters without commas is indeed the only acceptable syntax for resetting multiple counters (I tried on Chrome and with the Flying Saucer HTML to PDF processor)